# EL tag not working with maven in tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, jsp, maven, tomcat, jstl

EL tags not rendering when jsp page is called.
    `<c:out value="${uploadedImage.value.getDocumentName()}"/>`

prints the ${uploadedImage.value.getDocumentName()}

my pom file is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>                    
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>ImageManagement</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

My web.xml is

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
</web-app>
```

Web app have all the Servlet mapping.

My project Configuration is 
Tomcat 7.0
Eclipse kepler

```
<c:if test = "${not empty uploadedImages}">
<% int i = 0; %>
    <c:forEach var="uploadedImage" items="${uploadedImages}">
        <tr>
            <% i++; %>
            <td><%= i %></td>
            <td><c:out value="${uploadedImage.value.getDocumentName()}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${uploadedImage.value.getDocumentSize()}"/></td>
            <!-- <td><img src="image?id=${uploadedImage.value.getUserRepositryId()}" style = "height : 80px; width : 50px" alt = "image here"/></td>-->

            <td>
                <a href = "delete?id=${uploadedImage.value.getUserRepositryId()}"> Delete </a>
                <a href = "edit?id=${uploadedImage.value.getUserRepositryId()}"> Edit </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

uploadedImages is a HashMap variable which is set is the Session object.
it fetches the Saved images from the Database and saved it the HashMap.
Database part is working fine it loads the images from the Database and saved them in the HashMap.

The only problem is in working EL tag.
This project is working fine without maven.

UserRepositryDTO.java

```
public class UserRepositryDTO {
private int userRepositryId;
private int userId;
private String documentName;
private long documentSize;

private byte[] document;
private String message;


/**
 * @return the message
 */
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
/**
 * @param message the message to set
 */
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
/**
 * @return the userRepositryId
 */
public int getUserRepositryId() {
    return userRepositryId;
}
/**
 * @return the userId
 */
public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
/**
 * @return the documentName
 */
public String getDocumentName() {
    return documentName;
}
/**
 * @return the documentSize
 */
public long getDocumentSize() {
    return documentSize;
}

/**
 * @return the document
 */
public byte[] getDocument() {
    return document;
}
/**
 * @param userRepositryId the userRepositryId to set
 */
public void setUserRepositryId(int userRepositryId) {
    this.userRepositryId = userRepositryId;
}
/**
 * @param userId the userId to set
 */
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
/**
 * @param documentName the documentName to set
 */
public void setDocumentName(String documentName) {
    this.documentName = documentName;
}
/**
 * @param documentSize the documentSize to set
 */
public void setDocumentSize(long documentSize) {
    this.documentSize = documentSize;
}

/**
 * @param document the document to set
 */
public void setDocument(byte[] document) {
    this.document = document;
}
}
```

UserDTO.java

```
public class UserDTO {
private int userId;
private String username;
private String message;
private long totalSize;
private Map<Integer,UserRepositryDTO> userRepositry;

/**
 * @return the totalSize
 */
public long getTotalSize() {
    return totalSize;
}
/**
 * @param totalSize the totalSize to set
 */
public void setTotalSize(long totalSize) {
    this.totalSize = totalSize;
}

/**
 * @return the userId
 */
public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
/**
 * @return the username
 */
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
/**
 * @return the message
 */
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
/**
 * @param userId the userId to set
 */
public void setUserId(final int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
/**
 * @param username the username to set
 */
public void setUsername(final String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
/**
 * @param message the message to set
 */
public void setMessage(final String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public Map<Integer,UserRepositryDTO> getUserRepositry() {
    return userRepositry;
}
public void setUserRepositry(Map<Integer,UserRepositryDTO> userRepositry) {
    this.userRepositry = userRepositry;
}
}
```

The problem is due to the different version of servlet jsp jstl. i dont know the correct version.

Comment: you using EL invalid.. try `${uploadedImage.value.documentName}`

Comment: <c:out value="${uploadedImage.value.getDocumentName()}"/> this is valid because getDocumentName is function which return the Name of the Document

Comment: please add the class where you have `getDocumentName()`. the dependency you added in OP is usefulness..

Answer (score 0):

First, Don't use `Scriptlets(<%= %>)` to get index of loop, you can get index from `<c:forEach` tag by defining `varStatus`.

Am considering you have added `uploadedImages`(`Map`) object to request on your servlet.

```
req.setAttribute("uploadedImages", uploadedImages);
```

for iterating `uploadedImage` objects from `uploadedImages` Map in jsp do like:

import jstl taglib in top of your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

then,

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty uploadedImages}">
    <c:forEach var="uploadedImage" items="${uploadedImages}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <!--Her, don't use Scriptlets to get index, get index from <c:forEach varStatus -->
            <td>${status.index}</td> 
            <td><c:out value="${uploadedImage.value.documentName}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${uploadedImage.value.documentSize}"/></td>
            <!-- <td><img src="image?id=${uploadedImage.value.userRepositryId}" style = "height : 80px; width : 50px" alt = "image here"/></td>-->

            <td>
                <a href = "delete?id=${uploadedImage.value.userRepositryId}"> Delete </a>
                <a href = "edit?id=${uploadedImage.value.userRepositryId}"> Edit </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
   uploadedImages Map is empty..
</c:otherwise>
<c:choose>
```

to get propety value from DTO in expression-language(`${ }`) or jstl(`<c:` tag) do like:

in EL:

```
${uploadedImage.value.documentName} <!--internally EL will invoke getDocumentName() to get documentName value-->
```

in JSTL:

```
<c:out value="${uploadedImage.value.documentName}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your web.xml. It is declaring that it uses Servlet 2.3 which equates to JSP 1.2 where EL is not supported.

Try using something like following:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0"
         metadata-complete="true">
</web-app>
```